# After installing meld via pip, I can't run it

Tags: software-installation, python, meld

I've installed meld as a non-root user via `pip install meld` (on a relatively old distribution - SLES 15).

After installation, I see a file named `/home/joeuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/meld/meld.py` ; but no `meld` executable on my path. And if I try to run that, I get:

```
$ python3.6 /home/ctuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/meld/meld.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ctuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/meld/meld.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'utils'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which meld are you looking for - http://meldmerge.org/? `pip install meld` would install https://pypi.org/project/meld/ which does not look like an application,

Comment: @Wieland Oh! I did mean meld-the-application...